# Ways to say "Can't be bothered!"

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

How else can I express a feeling similar to "can't be bothered!"

Words or phrases would be appreciated as well as variations from across the English speaking world.

Answer (score 4):

In the current vernacular, **meh!** or **whatever**. The latter should be pronounced "wadever" and accomanied by a shrug or dismissive wave of the hand.

More formal words include **[apathetic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/apathetic)**, **[unconcerned](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unconcerned)**, **[uninterested](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/uninterested)**.

Answer (score 4):

I was going to give a list of verbs that you could replace "bothered" with to achieve the same meaning, but I [can't be arsed](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/can%27t+be+arsed).

Comment: My friend started using 'I can't be arsed' lately and it really annoys everyone, and after he uses it we all have a go at him. So please DO NOT use 'I can't be arsed' unless you want to be made fun of.

Answer (score 2):

[*I don't give a hoot ...*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/give+a+hoot)

*I don't give/care a hang ...*

*I don't give a damn ...*

*I don't give a goddamn shit ...*

*I don't give a goddamn fuck ...*

Answer (score 1):

*I couldn't care less …*
*Why bother?*

Or, one of my personal favorites:

*I'm going to get a sandwich.*

This one requires a bit of comedic timing. Someone tells you something they believe to be of grave importance, and you stand up, and announce that you are going to do something trivial rather than address their concern.  If you pull off the timing, it is a great one!

Or, another personal favorite:

*Good luck with all that …*

Again, timing and a disinterested (or sarcastic) tone are critical here …